# add number between string then render it in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried this with console.log and it works, but I am stuck on how to turn it into a div

```
let N = 13;
let nums = Array.apply(1, { length: N }).map(Number.call, Number)

console.log(nums)
for (let el of nums) {
  if (el <= 9) {
    time = `0`+el+`:00`;
                    
    console.log(time);
        
  } else if (el >= 9) {
    time = el+`:00`
    console.log(time);
  }
}
```

I want to put it in jsx

```
class SchedulePage extends React.Component {
    render(){
        
        return (
            <div className="schedule-page-container">
                {right here}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little of your react code?

Comment: What do you mean "turn it into a div" ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but have you tried storing the result in a variable (or state) and render that?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: This abomination `Array.apply(1, { length: N }).map(Number.call, Number)` can be replaced with `[...Array(N).keys()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this? Render one `div` for each number in your nums array:

```
class SchedulePage extends React.Component {
    render(){
        let N = 13;
        let nums = Array.apply(1, { length: N }).map(Number.call, Number);
        return (
            <div className="schedule-page-container">
                {nums.map(el => {
                    const time = el <= 9 ? `0${el}:00` : `${el}:00`;
                    return <div key={time}>{time}</div>;
                 })
               }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SchedulePage extends React.Component {

renderElement() {
let N = 13;
let nums = Array.apply(1, { length: N }).map(Number.call, Number)
let time
console.log(nums)
            for (let el of nums) {
                if (el <= 9) {
                    time = `0`+el+`:00`;
                    
                 
        
                }else if(el >= 9){
                    time = el+`:00`
                }
            }
return time
}   
render(){
        
        return (
            <div className="schedule-page-container">
                {this.renderElement()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to save the value somewhere and display it. Pass it down as prop, save it as an instance variable or in your state, there are many options.

```
class SchedulePage extends React.Component {
constructor(){
super(props);
let N = 13;
let nums = Array.apply(1, { length: N }).map(Number.call, Number)
let time = '';
          console.log(nums)
            for (let el of nums) {
                if (el <= 9) {
                    time = `0`+el+`:00`;
                    
                    console.log(time);
        
                }else if(el >= 9){
                    time = el+`:00`
                    console.log(time);
                }
            }

this.state = {
'val' : time 
};

}
    render(){
        
        return (
            <div className="schedule-page-container">
                {val}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Everytime the value of val changes, render will be called. So if this is something changing continuously, take a function outside and call it instead of keeping it in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Do `setState(time)` in your condition

```
   let N = 13;
   let nums = Array.apply(1, { length: N }).map(Number.call, Number)

   console.log(nums)
        for (let el of nums) {
            if (el <= 9) {
                time = `0`+el+`:00`;
                setState(time)
                console.log(time);
    
            }else if(el >= 9){
                time = el+`:00`
                setState(time)
                console.log(time);
            }
        }
```

After that declare state and render state with `this.state.time`

```
  class SchedulePage extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {time : ""};
      }
      render(){
    
        return (
          <div className="schedule-page-container">
             {rhis.state.time}
          </div>
      );
      }
  }
```

Next thing you need to do is when your function triggering to run

Answer (score 1):

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

class SchedulePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let N = 13;
    let nums = Array.apply(1, { length: N }).map(Number.call, Number);

    function renderTime(nums) {
      let time;
      for (let el of nums) {
        if (el <= 9) {
          time = `0` + el + `:00`;
        } else if (el >= 9) {
          time = el + `:00`;
        }
      }
      return time;
    }

    return <div className="schedule-page-container">{renderTime(nums)}</div>;
  }
}

export default SchedulePage;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    numLength: 13,
    nums: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let numArray = Array.apply(1, { length: this.state.numLength }).map(
      Number.call,
      Number
    );
    this.setState({ nums: numArray });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="schedule-page-container">
      
        {this.state.nums.map(el=>{
         return  <>{el <= 9?`0${el}:00`:`${el}:00`}</>
        })}
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Try it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kjqzhx